# Camouflage Net hair particle material help

Tags: texturing, particles, shaders

I have modelled a plane as a camouflage net using cloth physics. The net has a camouflage pattern with 4 colours. I want to apply hair particles to the net to give it a leafy texture. However I cannot work out how to make the hair particles (which are instanced from a separate object) take on the colour of the texture they emit from.

The images below explains it a little more I think.

[image: Particle texture coordinate Object]
[image: Particle texture coordinate UV]

This image is a close up of a section of the net. The particle object is selected. The particles do not take on the correct colour for the patch they are emitted from. Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Cycles. The net shader settings are the same as the particle object, however they do not have an assigned object, and from instancer is not selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Should work in Cycles. Both objects uses UVs?

Comment: @lemon yes, both use UVs, but I can't for the life of me work out why the colours are mismatching

Comment: The second picture (which is the good one as using Uvs) looks like you're rendering using Eevee. Is it rendered viewport shading?

Comment: @lemon I'm afraid I'm quite new to Blender, and have only just moved from 2.7, so I'm not very sure that means? EDIT - that fixed it, it wasnt in viewport rendered shading.

Comment: thanks very much!